# How does UI design differ when designing a software appliance console from traditional web applications?

Tags: java, user-interface, usability

- Are there any open source frameworks that are for this purpose?
- How does UI design differ when designing a software appliance console from traditional web applications?
- Any examples of particularly well-design user interfaces for software appliances?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "software appliance"?

Comment: Anyone know of empirical studies on the intersection of usability and configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'd find [Alan Coopers](http://www.cooper.com/) book [About Face](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470084111) quite useful. I have the 1st edition of this, and it talks about various *postures* of an application.

In your case, a software appliance console is an example of a *transient posture* application - one where you cannot assume users have prior knowledge or experience. This leads to various decisions - from offering fewer choices, to including more on-screen guidance.

There's more to this than I can describe here, go buy, borrow or steal a copy to read yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Just been through this recently.  First rule is make it simpler than you would make a web application.  Simpler in design, because you want it to be as reliable as possible.  Simpler in functionality because an appliance tends to stay in use for a long time; you don't want to be vulnerable to the vagaries of new browsers.